# Preview image with dynamically created input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make a button to dynamically create input field. After uploading file the image should be previewed . But find that , at first one image is previewed , then 2nd time after selecting file 2 copy of same image is previewed, then 3rd time 3 copy of same image and goes on…

Html code

```
<form method="post" action=" " class="form" id="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<div class="field" align="left"> 
<h3>Upload your images</h3>
<input type="text" placeholder="Event name">
<input type="file" id="1" class="gallery_input" name="files[]" multiple />
</div>
```

Js code

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var event_id=3;
   var input_id;

  $(document).ready(function ()
 {
 function readURL(input)
 {
    if(input.files && input.files[0])
    {
      var reader=new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function(e) {
      var file = e.target;
      $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
        "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
        "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
        "</span>").insertAfter("#"+input_id);
      $(".remove").click(function(){
        $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
      }); 
    });
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
 }


 $("body").click(function()
{
  $(".gallery_input").change(function()
    {
      var target_input=$(this).attr('id');
      input_id=target_input;
        readURL(this);
    });
 });
});
 </script>
```

If I remove

```
    $("body").click(function()
```

line it’s work . But I need this because it work’s with dynamically created
  input filed .
I remove some HTML and js code like input filed create Js code, etc. Because I think it works.

Comment: `$(function() { $("#form").on("change",".gallery_input",function() { ... }); $("#form").on("click",".remove",function() { ... }); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attachment of event handlers using `jQuery.on()` (and its shortcut methods `.click()`, `.change()` etc) doesn't work quite the way you think. Each time a handler is attached in this way, it is *added* to any handlers already attached. This behaviour is different from `foo.onclick = fn`, which *replaces* a previously attached handler.

So, as it stands ...

- each time `body` is clicked, a further change handler is attached to all `.gallery_input` element(s) on the page.
- each time `reader.onload` fires, a further click handler is attached no only to the `.remove` element in the fresh content, but is also added to the `.remove` elements in previously appended content.

The code can be fixed in a number of ways, chief amongst which (as indicated above by @mplungjan) is to permanently delegate `change` and `click` handling to the `form`, and to simplify `readURL()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function readURL(e) {
        var input = e.target;
        if(input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var file = e.target;
                $("<span class=\"pip\"><img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + file.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/><br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span></span>").insertAfter(input); // you already know `input` so it doesn't need to be rediscovered with `'#'+input_id`
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $("#form")
    .on('change', '.gallery_input', readURL)
    .on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
    });
});
```

The `$("body").click(...)` handler appears to be unnecessary and has disappeard.